# C compiler creates .obj files from .h files

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, linker, header

Should C Compiler (I use Visual Studio) generate .obj files from .h files? I think it shouldn't, but my compiler creates them. How do I fix it? There is no .c files except Main.c
[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you build the project?

Comment: A header file is a source file where you by convention avoid certain things.

Comment: Maybe remove the headers from your project settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C compiler will generate an object file for each source specified on the command line with the `-c` option.  Do not specify header files on the command line.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't found the way I can change cmd arguments, but moving code from old files to new created worked for me.